# Applet signed throw: java.security.AccessControlException. How can I make it run?

Tags: java, sockets, ftp, applet, policy

After hours of work (I'm not a java programmer) I've managed to pack and put inside an applet wich make an ftp-upload to a remote server. The main file is "prova.class" inside "invia.jar"; I use a third-part library, placed in "edtftpj.jar". I have signed both file and included them in the page with the following code:

**Index.html**

```
<applet width="300" height="300"  classpath="./" code="prova.class" archive="invio.jar,edtftpj.jar"> </applet>
```

now, when I point the browser to my page I found this message on the consolle:

```
Could not read property 'edtftp.log.level' due to security permissions
Could not read property 'edtftp.log.log4j' due to security permissions
Could not read property 'edtftp.log.log4j' due to security permissions
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission www.artkiller-web.com resolve)
 at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(Unknown Source)
 at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.connect(FTPClient.java:966)
 at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient.connect(FileTransferClient.java:386)
 at prova.start(prova.java:44)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any Idea of how to work-it around?

thank u in advance

ArtoAle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the connection url in a privileged block of code.

Also looks like you are having issues reading from the properties file, The properties file you can package right in your jar, if your trying to read the properties file from the client machine you will need to wrap that code in a privileged block of code as well.

Here is a block of code I used in a another answer for getting a URL through the access controller.

```
 try 
 {
     final String imageURL = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif";
     URL url = (URL) AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() 
     {

         public Object run() 
         {
             try
             {
               return new URL(imageURL);
             }
             catch (MalformedURLException e)
             {
               e.printStackTrace();
               return null;
             }

        }  
      });  

     if(url == null)
     {
        // Something is wrong notify the user
     }
     else
     {
        // We know the url is good so continue on
         img = ImageIO.read(url);
     }

  } 
  catch (IOException e) 
  {
   System.out.println(e);
  }
```